# How is unsupervised deep learning used in sentiment analysis?

Tags: deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, unsupervised-learning

Typically text classification, including sentiment analysis  can be performed in one of 2 ways: 1. Supervised learning if there is enough training data and 2. A unsupervised training when there is no enough training data which is not prelabeled

I have only a collection of tweets which contains only the texte (reviews) and there is no polarity fir each twwet.
My question is is there any method to di sentimeent analysis on this data using unsupervised learning?

Thank you to help me

Comment: You are specifically interested in unsupervised deep learning, or just any unsupervised learning?  (Your title and tag mention deep learning, but the body of your question does not.)

Comment: Thank you Darren for your reply. Since i have data whitout class, i am looking for an unsupervised learning. Any idea for this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

(Based on your comment, I've concentrated on the "unsupervised" part of your question, and ignored deep learning.)

If you use something like [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/) you can assign a positive or negative score to each word in a tweet, and then (as the simplest approach) sum them to get a single sentiment number for each tweet.

At this point it doesn't really matter if you are doing supervised or unsupervised learning, as either way you will have a score for each tweet, and can divide them up the tweets into, say, positive, neutral and negative sentiment. What the supervised data, the class, *does* allow is getting an error estimate on how well it has done at classifying them.

If you want an error estimate when your training data has no classes, you could evaluate some percentage of the tweets yourself. Even just doing 30 of them will start to give you an idea of where your grouping algorithm is on the scale from random to perfect, and won't take long.